# Throw an aggregate exception from a task won't break all other tasks

Tags: c#, task

I have two tasks:

```
try
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func(param));
    tasks.Add(task1);
    if (someCondition)
    {
        Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func2(param2));
        tasks.Add(task2);
     }

     tasksArr = tasks.ToArray();

     Task.WaitAll(tasksArr);
 }
 catch (AggregateException e)
 {
     //handle
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
     //handle
 }
```

If an exception occurs in one of the tasks, I'm throwing a new aggregation exception, but 'm reaching the catch statement only after the second task finishes. I want to catch it immediately, in order to stop unnecessary work in the second task.

I tried to use a cancellation token:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task.WaitAll(tasksArr,cts.Token);
```

But this wasn't a good solution since it requires that the inner exception will be handled + the caught exception will be an `OperationCanceledException`

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems `func(param)` and `func2(param2)` do not support cancellation by themselves because an instance of `CancellationToken` is not passed as parameter for `Task` and its delegate (method) (see [How to: Listen for Cancellation Requests by Polling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191559.aspx)). How can they be stopped without `CancellationToken`? Maybe you want to **cancel waiting** if one of the tasks fails?

Comment: I want to reach the **catch** statement, I guess that canceling the wait can be a solution, since currently i'm reaching the catch statement after all the tasks are completed. how can I **cancel waiting** if one of tasks failes? cts.cancel will cancel all the  tasks but the _innerexception_ gets lost

Answer (score 0):

To cancel waiting it is necessary to pass an instance of `CancellationTokenSource` class to [Task.WaitAll Method (Task[], CancellationToken)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321280.aspx). Also, use a *continuation* on each task that runs when a task fails (faults, i.e. `TaskStatus.Faulted`).

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

var tasks = new List<Task>();

var firstTask = new Task(FirstMethod);
firstTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First task exception: {0}", t.Exception);
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
tasks.Add(firstTask);
firstTask.Start();

var secondTask = new Task(SecondMethod);
secondTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second task exception: {0}", t.Exception);
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
tasks.Add(secondTask);
secondTask.Start();

try
{
    var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    var tasksArray = tasks.ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(tasksArray, cancellationToken);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // ...
}
```